# Find indices of nan elements in nested lists and remove them

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
names=[['Pat','Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
values=[[1, 9, 1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]]
```

I have 2 lists: `names` and `values`. Each value goes with a name, i.e., `Pat` corresponds to the value `1` and `Sam` corresponds to the value `9`.

I would like to remove the `nan` from `names` and the corresponding values from `values`.

That is, I want a `new_names` list that looks like this:

```
[['Pat','Sam', 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
```

and a `new_values` list that looks like this:

```
[[1, 9, 2, 1], [1, 1, 5, 10]]
```

My attempt was to first find the indices of these `nan` entries:

```
all_nan_idx = []
for idx, name in enumerate(names):
  if pd.isnull(name):
  all_nan_idx.append(idx)
```

However, the above does not account nested lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

names=[['Pat','Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
values=[[1, 9, 1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]]

new_names = []
new_values = []
for names_, values_ in zip(names, values):
    n = []
    v = []
    for name, value in zip(names_, values_):
        if not pd.isnull(name):
            n.append(name)
            v.append(value)
    new_names.append(n)
    new_values.append(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a hard-to-read comprehension that would do this but here's a step-by-step approach:

```
import numpy as np

names = [
    ['Pat', 'Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''],
    ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]
    ]
values = [
    [1, 9, 1, 2, 1],
    [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]
    ]

new_names = []
new_values = []

for nn, vv in zip(names, values):
    new_names.append([])
    new_values.append([])
    for n, v in zip(nn, vv):
        if not n is np.nan:
            new_names[-1].append(n)
            new_values[-1].append(v)


print(new_names)
print(new_values)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Pat', 'Sam', 'Tom', ''], ['Angela', 'James', '.', 'Jackie']]
[[1, 9, 2, 1], [1, 1, 5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too much, but here is another option:

```
import numpy as np

names = [['Pat', 'Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
values = [[1, 9, 1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]]

new_names = []
new_values = []

for aux_list in zip(names, values):
    filtered_names, filtered_values = zip(*filter(lambda x: x[0] is not np.nan, zip(*aux_list)))
    new_names.append(list(filtered_names))
    new_values.append(list(filtered_values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function:

```py
import numpy as np

def filter_nan(names, values):
  new_names, new_values = [], []

  for name, value in zip(names, values, strict=True):
    if name is np.nan:
      continue

    if isinstance(name, list) and isinstance(value, list):
      name, value = filter_nan(name, value)

      new_names.append(name)
      new_values.append(value)

  return new_names, new_values
```

Try it:

```py
names = [['Pat', 'Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
values = [[1, 9, 1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]]

print(filter_nan(names, values))

'''
(
  [['Pat', 'Sam', 'Tom', ''], ['Angela', 'James', '.', 'Jackie']],
  [[1, 9, 2, 1], [1, 1, 5, 10]]
)
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

This is better and less complicated way to deal with such situations

```
import numpy as np

names=[['Pat','Sam', np.nan, 'Tom', ''], ["Angela", np.nan, "James", ".", "Jackie"]]
values=[[1, 9, 1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1, 5, 10]]

new_names = []
new_values = []

for i in range(len(names)):
    new_names.append([])
    new_values.append([])
    for j in range(len(names[i])):
        if not isinstance(names[i][j], float):
            new_names[i].append(names[i][j])
            new_values[i].append(values[i][j])
            
print(new_names)
print(new_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org):

```
import pandas as pd


result = []
for n, v in zip(names, values):
    n = pd.Series(n).dropna()
    result.append((n.tolist(), pd.Series(v).loc[n.index].tolist()))

names, values = map(list, zip(*result))
```

You can also use a one-liner (if you're using Python >= 3.8):

```
import pandas as pd

names, values = map(list, zip(*(
    ((s := pd.Series(n).dropna()).tolist(), pd.Series(v).loc[s.index].tolist())
    for n, v in zip(names, values)
)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this efficiently in one statement, you can transpose the input lists into sequences of name-value pairs so you can filter out null names with a generator expression and then transpose them back into two lists:

```
new_names, new_values = map(list, zip(*(
    map(list, zip(*(
        (name, value)
        for name, value in zip(*pairs)
        if not pd.isnull(name)
    )))
    for pairs in zip(names, values)
)))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/EnormousHarshFreesoftware#main.py